# Trying to do grep and sed from a file and push the output into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sed

Can we do grep and sed from a file and push the output into a variable

```
grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed '{'s/=.*//'}'
```

Output would be like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001ef50fcb0f778b86-part3
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001ef50fcb0f778b86-part2
```

Error:

```
[/~]# grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'} >> $x
-bash: $x: ambiguous redirect
```

Can we push all 3 lines into a variable and call them with foreach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested, and both the below work in bash shell:

```
x=`grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'}`
x=$(grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'})
```

Notice first line is backticks, not single quotes.

The >> character in your question sends output to files, not variables.

To answer second part, yes, using output from above, a for loop works:

```
for line in $x 
do
  echo $line
done
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! I tried both methods. No go. Here is what I see :

<br>[root@localhost ~]# x=$(grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-" /tmp/del.txt | sed {'s/=.//'}) <br/>

[root@localhost ~]# $x
-bash: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb: Permission denied <br/>

[root@localhost ~]# x=$(grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/del.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'}) <br/>

[root@localhost ~]# $x
-bash: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb: Permission denied

Comment: Sorry for the messy log snip. it is giving this error -- `-bash: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb: Permission denied` or `-bash: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb,1171becbace78: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Jes it looks like you are trying to execute `$x`. Don't do that; it's data, not a command. If you want to see what `$x` contains, use `echo "$x"`.